# Use html tags in php mail

Tags: php, html, css

I have template php mailer, but i can't use html tags in my php mailer.

formhandler.php

```
private function compose_mail($post)
{
    $content = "Müraciətçinin məlumatları: \n\n";
    foreach($post as $name=>$value)
    {
        $content .= ucwords($name).":\n";
        $content .= "$value\n\n";
    }
    $this->mailer->Body  = $content;
}
```

handler.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;

$pp = new FormHandler(); 
$validator = $pp->getValidator();

$pp->sendEmailTo('yelmar.nihad@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: Try `$content .= $value."\n\n";`

Comment: <h2>Mobil:
236633636

</h2> this result in my mail. :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use br  tag instead of /n.

br  is a HTML line-break, whereas \n is a newline character in the source code.

In other words, br  will make a new line when you view the page as rendered HTML, whereas \n will make a new line when you view the source code.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I can, i want use <table> and other tags for design. But html tags not working

Comment: use Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 in header

Comment: I try this add after $content , but not worked, can u add this to my code?

Comment: @Artic What does your $content contain ? <html> tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
$to = 'to@email.com';
$headers = 'Set_bcc_here';
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$message = '<h1>Your message / content</h1>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

also try adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in your html head.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td> /* Your content Here */</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i add this codes, but not working. I send my files to you, can add this codes to my php files?

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = '<table width="80%" cellpadding="3" background="#e0f2f6">
            <tr>
                <td><h3> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Registration Email</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div>
                        <p>Dear, '.$userName.'</p>
                        <p>
                            Well Come to our website & Thank you for register here. we are send this email for verify your email and account on our website. Your verification link is <b><a href="#">Click Here</a></b>. 
                        </p>
                        <p>Website Name,<br />
                            Thank You,
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><strong itemprop="name">Your Address here,</strong><br>
                CityName-110011, Country.<br>
                    +00-0000000000 <br />
                    <a href="#">info@website.com</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but html codes not working in my php file, i want fix this :)

Comment: Add this line on top of your code and Try -->> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8mb4');